# Geting a variable from one webpage to 2 web pages using $_Get when a link is clicked

Tags: php, html

Hey guys how can I send one variable to 2 web pages connect.inc.php and image.php when a link is clicked but only open another page e.g link.php using $_Get. Its not working for me as am not getting the variable. 
Am sending it from index.php as follows

```
<a href="link.php?connectlink.inc.php?num=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES,        `'UTF-8'); ?>" ><h3 ><?php echo htmlspecialchars($data[$key], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?> </h3></a>` 
<p >
```

and this is what am using to retrieve it at connectlink.php and image.php

```
$numb= $_GET['num'];
```

Am not getting any errors bt am also not geting the variable to the 2 php files

Comment: Are you supposed to stay on one of those pages?

Comment: include those 2 files in link.php so that those 2 files can get those variables

Answer (score 0):

You should use & when adding more than one GET parameters:

```
<a href="link.php?connectlink.inc.php&num=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES,        `'UTF-8'); ?>" ><h3 ><?php echo htmlspecialchars($data[$key], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?> </h3></a>
```

Comment: Why are there two php files in the link? link.php and connectlink.inc.php?

Comment: Iam trying to pass the values to both of them at once

Comment: I am afraid you can't do that. You can achieve something like that via AJAX calls attached to your click event.